# How to use GROUP BY in SQL subquery without arithmetic count

Tags: sql, subquery

The result are many repeat rows (all conlums repeat)
how use group by without inner join?
I ned use a subquery inn this case.

This is fictional example, don't worry the logic or sense this example. I need use group by in subquery from many tables.

I can use group by with inner join, but this case I can't use inner join.

```
select    
    NAME,
    AGE,
    JOB

from (
    select 
        pe.name NAME,
        pe.age AGE,
        jb.work JOB
    from 
        pearson pe,
        job jb
    )
group by NAME, AGE, JOB
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: perhaps you should add Oracle tag since that link is for Oracle?

Comment: Unfortunately (so far as I'm concerned) your fictional example is *too abstract* for me to work out *what you're trying to do*. At the least, some *sample data* and *expected results* might make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a group by in this case, but you will need to create an alias name of the inner query as shown below:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.AGE, A.JOB
FROM (
    SELECT pe.name NAME, pe.age AGE, jb.`function` JOB
    FROM pearson pe, job jb
) A
GROUP BY A.NAME, A.AGE, A.JOB;
```

Comment: If this is what's actually standing between the OP and their code working, they've done a shockingly bad job by *failing to mention the error message that this lack of an alias would generate*